# How to scrape the dividend yield on this website

Tags: python, scrape

I'm trying to scrape the dividend yield on this website (https://www.set.or.th/set/companyprofile.do?symbol=FTREIT&ssoPageId=4&language=en&country=US)

But it's wrapped in "col-xs-9 col-md-5" and this appears multiple times.

There's a piece of text "Dvd. Yield(%)" that only appears once.

I know how to search for "Dvd. Yield(%)" but don't know how to get to the next line which has the numeric dividend yield number.

Beginner in python so appreciate the advice! Thanks a million in advance!

```html
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://www.set.or.th/set/companyprofile.do?symbol=FTREIT&ssoPageId=4&language=en&country=US'
page = requests.get(URL)
print(page)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

results = soup.find_all('Dvd. Yield(%)')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first find the parent element and then go to the second child DIV element to obtain the required one. Here is the sample code:

```
result = soup.find('div', string='Dvd. Yield(%)') # finding the div element by text
parent = result.parent # finding the parent
dvd_yield = parent.find_next('div').find_next('div') # getting the second div child element
print(dvd_yield.text) # printing the result
```

Result:

```
3.83
```